# Using AutoComple ngTagsInput in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-http, ng-tags-input

In my project, i use ngTagsInput for tagging. I have a problem, I did `loadTags`. I got from API and I tried to change structure like `{text : sometag}`. And then my autocomplete tag is not working. even though I use `return` like tutorial in http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos.

**LoadTags to get Data from API**

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.253:81/agnes/ruang-vemale/api/v1/category/get/3c8dd5e26e7e653c9823728f90fcbadf39c2651e/";
    data = {
        username: "newshubid",
        data: {
            orderby: {
                field: "label",
                type: "DESC"
            }
        }
    };
    args = {
        "data": JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    param = $.param(args);
    HttpService("POST", url, param, function(response) {
        res = angular.fromJson(response.data);
        angular.forEach(res, function(item) {
            $scope.get_cat = {
                text: item.label
            };
            return $scope.get_cat;
        });
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="tag" class="bootstrap"
                                        replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
                                        on-tag-added="AttachTag($tag)"
                                        on-tag-removed="RemovedTag($tag)">
        <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Please help me and give me solution where I find my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind to create a working copy with sample json in plnkr/jsbin/jsfiddle... ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong `ng-model` binding for the `tag data`

Try, taking `$scope.get_cat` as an array and push each tag into it.

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
    var url = "http://192.168.0.253:81/agnes/ruang-vemale/api/v1/category/get/3c8dd5e26e7e653c9823728f90fcbadf39c2651e/";
    data = {
        username: "newshubid",
        data: {
            orderby: {
                field: "label",
                type: "DESC"
            }
        }
    };
    args = {
        "data": JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    param = $.param(args);
    HttpService("POST", url, param, function(response) {
        res = angular.fromJson(response.data);
        $scope.get_cat = []
        angular.forEach(res, function(item) {
            $scope.get_cat.push({
                text: item.label
            });

        });
        return $scope.get_cat;
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried your code but showing error in console.log like TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: try adding `var data` in third line

Comment: I think the problem is not var data in third line. Still not working

Comment: the problem is in `http response`

Comment: try `console.log(response)` and check what is coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137811/discussion-between-sravan-and-userpr).

Answer (score 0):

If you have read the documentation of the ngTagsInput properly.It is written that it expects a promise in return. I have made little change for you in your code. **$q** service is responsible for promise in angular. Now for this you need to inject **$q** in your controller. Hope it works.

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
        var url = "http://192.168.0.253:81/agnes/ruang-vemale/api/v1/category/get/3c8dd5e26e7e653c9823728f90fcbadf39c2651e/";
        data = {
            username: "newshubid",
            data: {
                orderby: {
                    field: "label",
                    type: "DESC"
                }
            }
        };
        args = {
            "data": JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        param = $.param(args);
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        HttpService("POST", url, param,
        function(response) {
            res = angular.fromJson(response.data);
            $scope.get_cat = []
            angular.forEach(res, function(item) {
                $scope.get_cat.push({
                    text: item.label
                });

            });
              deferred.resolve($scope.get_cat);
              return deferred.promise; 
        });
    };
```